# Release timeline for 128KB personal computers?

Tags: history, ram, home-computers

IBM, Apple, Commodore, and Atari all released upgraded versions of their popular home/personal computers having "stock" 128KB of RAM around the early 1980's.

What was the order of release (based on approximate shipping dates) for each of these new models? Also, did any other mass-market computer maker beat all of them to market with a "stock" 128KB home/personal computer?

*Note:* By "stock" I mean *minimum* 128KB as shipped.

Comment: This sounds quite like asking a list question, doesn't it?

Comment: No. The order is the answer, not the list.

Comment: How is it possible to conceive an order without listing the items?

Comment: A randomly ordered list is not a "timeline".

Comment: Ordering by year may not be  random ordered - still it'll be a list. The ordering criteria doesn't make it anything else. To become more than a list, the items would need to have a common evolution/relation past their introduction date. Can't see that, as the question doesn't ask for any evolution, but simply listing unrelated items with a specific attribute by year.

Comment: [The reasons given to explain why list questions aren’t appropriate](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/380/79) apply whether the list is ordered or not.

Comment: @StephenKitt: The main objections to list questions boil down to being open-ended, and not admitting a definitive answer.  This question isn’t so open-ended: it focuses on a small list of major manufacturers, within a limited time-frame, well in the past, and with a clear product criterion.  It’s much clearer to see how a definitive answer could be possible for this.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I’m not trying to judge whether this question is too open-ended or not; my point is that whether the list is ordered or not doesn’t have much bearing on that.

Comment: @Peter: The "what was the order of release of models from these manufacturers?" part of the question is in fact bounded with a single correct answer.  The "did any other mass-market computer maker beat all of them to market" is problematic though.

Comment: Just because they all came out roughly the same time didn't actually mean much.  Back then with the 8-24K of memory in a more/less "flat" configuration it was easier to code for.  But when we went above 64K, to 128K or higher, we had to learn how to use "Bank Switching" effectively to access the memory for our programs.  The most immediate application was actually a "RAM Disk" as serial speeds for floppy/magnetic/disk transfers (let alone tape loads) were long enough to want a small space to store small programs like DOS did.

Comment: Are you asking specifically for "128k" or "more than 64k" - I think the list should definitely include the quirky Spanish Amstrad CPC 472 (1985) that was a modified (but official) version of the CPC 464 with 8K of non-addressable (not even powered) additional RAM to circumvent  a specific Spanish home computer import tax.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Apple III came with a minimum of 128K of RAM (expandable to 512K) two years before Commodore had a series of CBM-II computers with 128K minimum and expandable to 896K in 1982 a year before the IBM PC XT and 2 years before the Apple Macintosh and IIc. The IBM PC had 64K minimum.

** The *upgrade* machines are those not flagged as **new**.

- 1980: Apple III (128K-512K, **new**)
- 1982: Tandy TRS-80 Model 16 (128K-512K)
- 1982: Commodore CBM-II 500 / 600 / 700 Series (128K-896K, **new**)
- 1983: IBM PC XT (128K-640K)
- 1983: Apple Lisa (1,024K, **new**)
- 1983: Apple III Plus (256K-512K)
- 1984: Apple Macintosh (128K, **new**)
- 1984: Apple IIc (128K-1,152K)
- 1984: IBM PC AT (512K-16,384K)
- 1984: Sinclair QL (128K-896K, **new**)
- 1985: Amstrad CPC 6128 (128K-576K)
- 1985: Amstrad PCW 8256 (256K-512K, **new**)
- 1985: Atari 520ST (512K, **new**)
- 1985: Atari 130XE (128K)
- 1985: Commodore 128 (128K)
- 1985: Commodore Amiga [1000] (256K-8,704K), **new**)
- 1985: Fujitsu FM 77 AV (128K-192K)
- 1985: Sinclair ZX Spectrum 128 (128K)
- 1985: Thomson TO9 (128K)
- 1985: Enterprise 128 (128K, **new**)
- 1986: BBC Master 128 (128K-512K)
- 1986: Tandy Color Computer 3 (128K-512K)

Comment: On the Atari side of things, the 520ST was available (in small quantities) a couple of before the 130XE!

Comment: 1982: Columbia Data Products MPC 1600-1 (128K)

Comment: Oops, “a couple of *months* before”. The C128 and both Ataris were announced in January 1985 at CES; the 520ST started shipping in April 1985, the 130XE in June. I don’t know about the C128.

Comment: 1984 also saw the Apple Macintosh 512K, only seven months after the 128K release in January, and just one month after the IBM PC/AT.

Comment: The Apple ///, IIRC, came out in June 1980. And it can qualify as an upgrade to the Apple II, being backwards compatible.

Comment: I'd disagree with tagging the Apple III "new". It was a backwards-compatible upgrade to the Apple II with many new features, much as the C128 was to the C64.

Comment: It wasn't actually very backward compatible. The Apple III wasn't an Apple II with enhancements, it was a completely different system with an Apple II mode that was crippled.

Comment: The Commodore 128 was said to be "only weeks away from shipping" at the June 1985 Summer CES according to the August 1985 (pg 14) issue of COMPUTE! magazine. Everything in magazines back then was a couple of months behind reality. The September issue had ads with the C128. I would conclude from this that the C128 started shipping sometime in July 1985.

Answer (score 17):

Soviet:

- ES PEVM (IBM PC clone) - 1986
- Okean-240 (128 KB, Intel 8080 class) - 1986
- UKNC (192 KB, PDP-11 class) - 1987
- DVK-3M (248 KB, PDP-11 class) - 1987
- Korvet (112-256 KB, Intel 8080 class) - 1987
- BK-0011 (128 KB, PDP-11 class) - 1989
- Poisk (IBM PC clone) - 1989
- Iskra-1030 (IBM PC clone) - 1989
- Agat (Apple clone) - 1989
- Bashkiria-2M (128 KB, Intel 8080 class) - 1989
- Orion-128 (128-256 KB, Intel 8080 class) - 1990

This list is incomplete, it does not include many ZX Spectrum clones.

Comment: The BK-0011 had 128KB of RAM? AFAIK that would've filled its entire address space. But it also had I/O, so it must've done paging somehow, right?

Comment: Also, have you considered the various ZX compatibles, such as ZS Scorpion which would've had 128K at least from the beginning.

Comment: @OmarL Yes, BK-0011(M) used paging. Some extension cards for it had as much as 512 KB additional RAM, which would make a total of 640KB.  This list is definitely incomplete. It does not include ZX-clones. There was also Agat, a clone of Apple (1989) and other less known such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besta_(computer).

Comment: I'm surprised to read that Besta had a 68020 processor? Despite the embargo? Or was it a Soviet-produced compatible CPU?

Comment: @OmarL the Russian article says it had legally-licensed OS ported by West-German firm Stollmann GmbH and many components were produced by another West-German firm Force Computers GmbH.

Comment: The 68000 was on the COCOM list, but "could be released by companies under their own discretion". I would assume that later on this was valid for its  derivates as well.

Comment: @tofro The fatory started production after a Gorbachev's visit, so it could be some part of Gorbachev's deal regarding reunification of Germany.

Answer (score 5):

This depends quite on the value of the *'minimum 128KB as shipped'* footnote.

For the Apple II, it was possible in 1983 to order a IIe with 64 or 128 KiB, but it wasn't until the IIc in 1984 that these 128 KiB were soldered in. Even the very last IIe, the Platimum, which was sold only with 128 KiB, had them factory installed as a (then very small) card in the AUX slot

Same case with the IBM PC. While the original (first) IBM PC motherboard could hold only 16 to 64 KiB, IBM offered the machine with up to 256 KiB, using shop installed ISA cards.

Comment: I took it to mean “systems which couldn’t be ordered with less than 128KiB of RAM”, which disqualifies the Apple ][ and IBM PC.

Comment: @StephenKitt Wouldn't that make any entry subject to random marketing decisions? Like offering a Platinum IIe with or without the added 64 KiB? The later was in fact possible, but not part of the default offering.

Comment: Indeed, perhaps “systems whose minimal supported configuration had 128KiB of RAM” would be better.